# Как удалить старую версию PHP Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, php7, php5

Как удалить старую версию PHP (точнее полностью php) в Ubuntu?

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.0 не помогает
```

Comment: В прошлом вопросе ещё не всё выяснили. Го туда.

Comment: Что конкретно не выходти? ошибку выдает? Apache стоит?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php7*
```

Answer (score 0):

Не делайте этого если у Вас уже есть на этом сервере рабочий сайт!
Хочу дополнить автора выше: sudo apt-get remove --purge php7.0*